# Accidently removed python by "sudo apt-get remove python"

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, python

I have accidently removed the default version of python that comes with ubuntu and it removed the some system dependencires with it.

Now I cannot reinstall by "sudo apt-get install python"

```
     sudo apt-get install python
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python is already the newest version (2.7.15~rc1-1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0 icu-devtools ieee-data libboost-atomic-dev libboost-atomic1.65-dev libboost-atomic1.65.1 libboost-chrono-dev libboost-chrono1.65-dev
  libboost-container-dev libboost-container1.65-dev libboost-container1.65.1 libboost-context-dev libboost-context1.65-dev libboost-context1.65.1 libboost-coroutine-dev
  libboost-coroutine1.65-dev libboost-coroutine1.65.1 libboost-date-time-dev libboost-date-time1.65-dev libboost-dev libboost-exception-dev libboost-exception1.65-dev
  libboost-fiber-dev libboost-fiber1.65-dev libboost-fiber1.65.1 libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-filesystem1.65-dev libboost-graph-dev libboost-graph-parallel-dev
  libboost-graph-parallel1.65-dev libboost-graph-parallel1.65.1 libboost-graph1.65-dev libboost-graph1.65.1 libboost-iostreams-dev libboost-iostreams1.65-dev
  libboost-locale-dev libboost-locale1.65-dev libboost-log-dev libboost-log1.65-dev libboost-math-dev libboost-math1.65-dev libboost-math1.65.1 libboost-mpi-dev
  libboost-mpi1.65-dev libboost-mpi1.65.1 libboost-numpy-dev libboost-numpy1.65-dev libboost-numpy1.65.1 libboost-program-options-dev libboost-program-options1.65-dev
  libboost-python1.65.1 libboost-random-dev libboost-random1.65-dev libboost-random1.65.1 libboost-regex-dev libboost-regex1.65-dev libboost-serialization-dev
  libboost-serialization1.65-dev libboost-serialization1.65.1 libboost-signals-dev libboost-signals1.65-dev libboost-signals1.65.1 libboost-stacktrace-dev
  libboost-stacktrace1.65-dev libboost-stacktrace1.65.1 libboost-system-dev libboost-system1.65-dev libboost-test-dev libboost-test1.65-dev libboost-test1.65.1
  libboost-thread-dev libboost-thread1.65-dev libboost-timer-dev libboost-timer1.65-dev libboost-timer1.65.1 libboost-tools-dev libboost-type-erasure-dev
  libboost-type-erasure1.65-dev libboost-type-erasure1.65.1 libboost-wave-dev libboost-wave1.65-dev libboost-wave1.65.1 libboost1.65-dev libboost1.65-tools-dev libfabric1
  libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin libgraphite2-dev libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0 libhwloc-dev libhwloc-plugins libhwloc5 libibverbs-dev libicu-dev
  libicu-le-hb-dev libicu-le-hb0 libiculx60 libjs-async libjs-inherits libjs-node-uuid libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libnuma-dev libopenmpi-dev libopenmpi2 libpcre16-3
  libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpsm-infinipath1 libpython-all-dev libpython-dev libpython2.7-dev librsync1 libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libssl1.0-dev libuv1-dev mpi-default-bin
  mpi-default-dev node-abbrev node-ansi node-ansi-color-table node-archy node-async node-balanced-match node-block-stream node-brace-expansion node-builtin-modules
  node-combined-stream node-concat-map node-cookie-jar node-delayed-stream node-forever-agent node-form-data node-fs.realpath node-fstream node-fstream-ignore
  node-github-url-from-git node-glob node-graceful-fs node-hosted-git-info node-inflight node-inherits node-ini node-is-builtin-module node-isexe node-json-stringify-safe
  node-lockfile node-lru-cache node-mime node-minimatch node-mkdirp node-mute-stream node-node-uuid node-nopt node-normalize-package-data node-npmlog node-once node-osenv
  node-path-is-absolute node-pseudomap node-qs node-read node-read-package-json node-request node-retry node-rimraf node-semver node-sha node-slide node-spdx-correct
  node-spdx-expression-parse node-spdx-license-ids node-tar node-tunnel-agent node-underscore node-validate-npm-package-license node-which node-wrappy node-yallist
  openmpi-bin openmpi-common pkg-config python-apt python2.7-dev zlib1g-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 209 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up python-dnspython (1.15.0-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-dnspython (--configure):
 installed python-dnspython package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-minimal (2.7.15~rc1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing package python-minimal (--configure):
 installed python-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-six (1.11.0-2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-six (--configure):
 installed python-six package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-apt (1.6.5ubuntu0.2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-apt (--configure):
 installed python-apt package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-dnspython
 python-minimal
 python-six
 python-apt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I did a check on what dependencies were removed by checking out /var/log/apt/history.log

```
Start-Date: 2020-03-19  21:01:03
Commandline: apt-get remove python
Requested-By: xxx (1000)
Remove: python-six:amd64 (1.11.0-2), python-tdb:amd64 (1.3.15-2), python-pathlib2:amd64 (2.3.0-1), python-xmltodict:amd64 (0.11.0-1), python-openssl:amd64 (17.5.0-1ubuntu1), python-jmespath:amd64 (0.9.3-1ubuntu1), python-samba:amd64 (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15), python-configparser:amd64 (3.5.0-1), python-logilab-common:amd64 (1.4.1-1), steam-launcher:amd64 (1.0.0.61), python-xdg:amd64 (0.25-4ubuntu1), python-markupsafe:amd64 (1.0-1build1), python-isort:amd64 (4.3.4+ds1-1), python-yaml:amd64 (3.12-1build2), python-requests:amd64 (2.18.4-2ubuntu0.1), python-simplejson:amd64 (3.13.2-1), node-gyp:amd64 (3.6.2-1ubuntu1), python-gi:amd64 (3.26.1-2ubuntu1), libboost-all-dev:amd64 (1.65.1.0ubuntu1), python-fasteners:amd64 (0.12.0-3), python-tk:amd64 (2.7.16-2~18.04), python-dbus:amd64 (1.2.6-1), python-libcloud:amd64 (2.2.1-1), python-pickleshare:amd64 (0.7.4-2), python-wcwidth:amd64 (0.1.7+dfsg1-1), slack-desktop:amd64 (4.3.2), python-monotonic:amd64 (1.1-2), gyp:amd64 (0.1+20150913git1f374df9-1ubuntu1), python-certifi:amd64 (2018.1.18-2), libboost-mpi-python1.65-dev:amd64 (1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5), python-chardet:amd64 (3.0.4-1), python-selinux:amd64 (2.7-2build2), python-mccabe:amd64 (0.6.1-2), python:amd64 (2.7.15~rc1-1), python-enum34:amd64 (1.1.6-2), python-pexpect:amd64 (4.2.1-1), python-lockfile:amd64 (1:0.12.2-2), python-kerberos:amd64 (1.1.14-1), npm:amd64 (3.5.2-0ubuntu4), python-cryptography:amd64 (2.1.4-1ubuntu1.3), python-crypto:amd64 (2.6.1-8ubuntu2), libboost-python1.65-dev:amd64 (1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5), python-keyrings.alt:amd64 (3.0-1), python-cffi-backend:amd64 (1.11.5-1), python-ipaddress:amd64 (1.0.17-1), python-ptyprocess:amd64 (0.5.2-1), python-lazy-object-proxy:amd64 (1.3.1-1), libboost-mpi-python-dev:amd64 (1.65.1.0ubuntu1), python-jinja2:amd64 (2.10-1ubuntu0.18.04.1), python-paramiko:amd64 (2.0.0-1ubuntu1.2), python-astroid:amd64 (1.6.0-1), python-scandir:amd64 (1.7-1), python-pygments:amd64 (2.2.0+dfsg-1), nginx-amplify-agent:amd64 (1.7.0-5~bionic), python-netaddr:amd64 (0.7.19-1), libboost-mpi-python1.65.1:amd64 (1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5), python-pkg-resources:amd64 (39.0.1-2), python-all:amd64 (2.7.15~rc1-1), python-apt:amd64 (1.6.5ubuntu0.2), python-urllib3:amd64 (1.22-1ubuntu0.18.04.1), python-secretstorage:amd64 (2.3.1-2), python-dev:amd64 (2.7.15~rc1-1), python-pyasn1:amd64 (0.4.2-3), python-setuptools:amd64 (39.0.1-2), python-prompt-toolkit:amd64 (1.0.15-1), python-keyring:amd64 (10.6.0-1), samba-common-bin:amd64 (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.15), pylint:amd64 (1.8.3-1), python-backports-shutil-get-terminal-size:amd64 (1.0.0-5), python-ipython:amd64 (5.5.0-1), nodejs-dev:amd64 (8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.4), python-decorator:amd64 (4.1.2-1), libboost-python-dev:amd64 (1.65.1.0ubuntu1), ipython:amd64 (5.5.0-1), python-traitlets:amd64 (4.3.2-1), python-singledispatch:amd64 (3.4.0.3-2), python-idna:amd64 (2.6-1), python-ipython-genutils:amd64 (0.2.0-1), python-concurrent.futures:amd64 (3.2.0-1), python-wheel:amd64 (0.30.0-0.2), duplicity:amd64 (0.7.17-0ubuntu1.1), python-ldb:amd64 (2:1.2.3-1ubuntu0.1), python-wrapt:amd64 (1.9.0-3), ansible:amd64 (2.5.1+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1), python-egenix-mxtools:amd64 (3.2.9-1), python-egenix-mxdatetime:amd64 (3.2.9-1), python-pip:amd64 (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.1), python-asn1crypto:amd64 (0.24.0-1), python-backports.functools-lru-cache:amd64 (1.4-2), python-simplegeneric:amd64 (0.8.1-1), python-all-dev:amd64 (2.7.15~rc1-1), python-httplib2:amd64 (0.9.2+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2020-03-19  21:01:24

Start-Date: 2020-03-19  21:01:58
Commandline: apt --fix-broken install
Requested-By: xxx (1000)
Install: python:amd64 (2.7.15~rc1-1, automatic)
End-Date: 2020-03-19  21:02:01
```

Could anyone please help me on how to proceed with fixing this?

TIA!

EDIT 1:

It looks like it remove pip as well and when reinstalling it. i observed the below error

```
Setting up python-dnspython (1.15.0-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-dnspython (--configure):
 installed python-dnspython package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

Comment: it says "python is already the newest version"  in the results. so that means it is not removed(?)

Comment: Yes but it doesn't allow me to remove/install some of the packages like steam-launcher 


Setting up python-apt (1.6.5ubuntu0.2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

Comment: @guiverc I am sorry. it's 18.04. I will edit it.